# Moralizer or moralist?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

Can anyone please explain the difference between words: moraliser and moralist? Which one has got more positive meaning? Which one would be more appropriate, for example, in such a sentence: Charles Dickens was a great moraliser/moralist.

Answer (score 2):

Both have negative connotations:

> **mor‧al‧ize**    also    moralise
>
> British English [intransitive]
>
> to tell other people your ideas about right and wrong behaviour,
>   **especially when they have not asked for your opinion [= preach]**:
>
> http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/moralize

And I am sure the above isn't only BrE, but also AmE.

Now about the other. See 3:

> **mor·al·ist** noun
>
> 1 :  one who leads a moral life
>
> 2 :  a teacher or student of morals :  a thinker or writer concerned
>   with moral principles and problems
>
> 3 :  one who is concerned to regulate the morals of others
>
> Merriam-Webster Unabridged Dictionary

However, I feel that the first has more of this negative connotation.

Comment: I thought so. A moraliser seems to be an intrusive preacher giving you a sermon when you don't ask for. Thanks.